# R calling a data frame by variable name inside coordinates function (of the sp package)

Tags: r, r-sp

I spent a while trying to understand why this is not working but I just couldn't figure it out.
I am working with the sp packages in R and I want to transform a data frame to a SpatialPointsDataFrame assigning the coordinates using the coordinates function. The data frame should be called dynamically.

Following the example of the "meuse" data:

```
> data(meuse)
> coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
> meuse
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 155 
extent      : 178605, 181390, 329714, 333611  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 12
names       : cadmium, copper, lead, zinc,   elev,       dist,   om, ffreq, soil, lime, landuse, dist.m 
min values  :     0.2,     14,   37,  113,  5.180, 0.00000000,  1.0,     1,    1,    0,      Aa,     10 
max values  :    18.1,    128,  654, 1839, 10.520, 0.88038900, 17.0,     3,    3,    1,       W,   1000
```

This works fine. Trying to call "meuse" dynamically, however, fails:

```
> df <- "meuse"
> data(list = df)
> coordinates(get(df)) <- ~x+y
Error in coordinates(get(df)) <- ~x + y : could not find function "get<-"
```

Why doesn't this work? And why is it trying to find a "get<-" function?

My Workaround so far is:

```
assign(df, `coordinates<-`(get(df), ~x+y))
```

Comment: "And why is it trying to find a "get<-" function?" https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Function-calls

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is because get(df) is not an lvalue, i.e. something you can assign a value to.